# Draw line animation in libGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

I am doing first game in libGdx. i have to do line draw animation like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bqcu94VuVOI)

here is my code to drawline

```
Vector2 start = new Vector2(10, 10);
Vector2 end = new Vector2(100,100);
ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer=new ShapeRenderer();
shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
shapeRenderer.line(start, end);
shapeRenderer.end();
```

i am able to draw direct line between 2 points but need to have with drawing animation.

any help?

Comment: You have over 7K reputation score and ask a question without showing us what you have tried?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the small code sample - to animate the line, simply make the 4 coordinate values dynamic (changing).

Comment: you can  try by drawing line into pieces of for loop containing very small line and also some amount of delay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your code, you simply need to make the coordinate values dynamic:

```
Vector2 startPt = null;
Vector2 endPt = null;
Vector2 movingPt = null;

void myInit()
{
  startPt = new Vector2(10, 10);
  endPt = new Vector2(100, 100);
  movingPt = new Vector2(startPt.x, startPt.y);
}

void update( float delta )
{
  // add your animation here, below is an example
  float PixelsPerSecond = 100f;
  float dt = delta * PixelsPerSecond;
  if ( movingPt.x < endPt.x ) movingPt.x += dt;
  else movingPt.x = endPt.x;
  if ( movingPt.y < endPt.y ) movingPt.y += dt;
  else movingPt.y = endPt.y;
}

void draw()
{

  // add code here (or in a base class) to clear the screen (once) each loop

  ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer=new ShapeRenderer();
  shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
  shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
  shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  shapeRenderer.line(startPt, movingPt);
  shapeRenderer.end();
}
```

Comment: I changed answer a bit.. now it's working perfectly, thanks!! :)

Comment: Ah, so you really wanted to animate the creation of the line :) glad the code helped...